# Select a particular portion from a html dump using regex based on a criteria using Unix commands

Tags: awk, grep, regular-expression, html

I am stuck with a question where I am supposed to display only those commands with a number of votes >= 1 from a dump of page http://www.commandlinefu.com using Unix commands. I am attaching a portion of the file in the link : https://pastebin.com/4dEQD5us. The votes and the commands are expressed in the following html tags:

```
    div class="num-votes"

    div class="command"
```

I tried selecting the command and votes tag using grep. But I don't how to put the conditions to get the desired answer.

Comment: [Don't.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/836748)

Answer (score 3):

At the bottom of [the page](http://www.commandlinefu.com/), there's a link to their [API](https://www.commandlinefu.com/site/api).  Reading and understanding that tells you that to get the data in a format that is suitable for parsing, such as JSON, you use, e.g.,

```
curl -s 'https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/browse/json'
```

That is a JSON document that you then easily extract the commands with  votes greater than zero from, using `jq`:

```
curl -s 'https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/browse/json' |
jq -r '.[] | select(.votes|tonumber > 0).command'
```

We need to convert `.votes` in each entry in the top-level array to a number since it's encoded as a string in the data. This is why we pass it through `tonumber` before comparing it to zero.